# Lyx Math issues - missing a cell

Tags: lyx, mactex

I used to have a default setting of three cells, when using math (cmd+m, enter). But at some point it has changed to only to cells, and when I add an additional colon, when there are not aligned.

I have tried to uninstall, reinstall and change version of LyX. 
I run Mactex and then Lyx on a MacBook Air.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not clear to me what's the problem and question here? Maybe you should give some further explanation or code if necessary. What does cmd+m do?

Comment: If I remember correctly, LyX used to use an `eqnarray` environment for the default aligned, display math. That is a bad idea (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196), so at some point this was changed to using an `align` environment. An `eqnarray` will have three columns per alignment, with the equality sign (or similar) in the middle column, but `align` will have two columns per alignment, and the equality sign should go in the right column.